# Get Classname of clicked html element in external js file Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, element

I'm trying to get the class name of the clicked html element.

I fix it... I create a function in my external JS file

Comment: Maybe something like this : $(a).on(‘click’, function(){ var className = $(this).className; });

Answer (score 1):

You can get the classes using `.className` on the element

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(this.className)
    })
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn myButton1"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> <span>Button 1</span></a>
<a href="#" class="btn myButton2"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> <span>Button 2</span></a>
```

Comment: Good answer. Would be more readable with forEach instead of for buttons.length in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, but I think this is not working for me. First of all I check a variable with 3 if statements. Each IF-Statement calls a different public.function(). The two of them works fine; The third is a mix of the two...so thats why I want to save the class name or ID of clicked element because I have to know if the user wants A or B.

Comment: @sokolata You should then post all the important code in the question. As it is I gave you a solution for the problem stated but can not help you if you dont post at least the important parts

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I Updated my first post.

Comment: @sokolata It is still the same. in your `click` listener you will use `this.className` to get the classes

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz It's not working. This snippet is working if I put the code in the index.php, but when I try to call the (this.className) in my JS-File then I get an error.
I tried also var button_clicked = this.className but then I get an other FULL <a>-Tag

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz The problem with your snippet is that the var can't be used outside of the for loop. This is also not working 

`var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(this.className) 
        var className = this.className;
    })
console.log(this.className)
console.log(className) }`

Answer (score 0):

The below code will select all of the anchor tags on the page.  You can loop through those and you'll see that each one has a className attribute and classList attribute.  You can add an event listener to toggle classes or whatever you want to do when an element is clicked.  This function below will print to the console and pop up an alert box.  In your case, you can just scope a variable that you toggle based on what is clicked.

```
let arrayOfAnchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
arrayOfAnchors.forEach(anchor => {
    console.log(anchor.className);
    console.log(anchor.classList);
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function() { console.log('hey there'); alert('hi'); });

});
```

Comment: Error, that arrayOfAnchors not defined.

Comment: I'm not using the IE

Comment: My fault, I declared the variable as `arrayOfAnchors` but then called it `arrayofAnchors` in the second line.  I fixed it so that it is camel cased on both `Of` and `Anchors`.

Comment: @tlm Same thing as the snippet from LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz. Not accessable in my Javascript file, only in index.php. My Buttons are placed in index.php but the functions in core.js. I need the clicked element in core.js.. Any ideas?

Comment: @tlm:  This is also not working ==> Console writes: Uncaught ReferenceError: clicked is not defined

`<script type="text/javascript">
 let arrayOfAnchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
 arrayOfAnchors.forEach(anchor => {
   var clicked = anchor.className;
     anchor.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('hey there'); alert(this.className); });
 });
 console.log(clicked);
 </script>`

Comment: `clicked` is not defined because it is outside of the scope of your `console.log` invocation.  When you put it inside the forEach, it isn't available outside of it.

Maybe you could try directly attaching the javascript function to the `onclick` attribute of your <a> tags.

Comment: I tried also this:
`$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
   var clicked_element = this.id;
   console.log(clicked_element);
 });`

This is "working", but I get every time the last id name -> in this case the ID of Button2 - I don't know why!

My HTML:
`<a href="#" class="btn myButton1"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> <span>Button 1</span></a>
<a href="#" class="btn myButton2"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> <span>Button 2</span></a>
`

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, don't use $(document) to bind events like that.  Instead you could try something like 
`$('a').on('click', function(){console.log(this.className)});`
That will bind the click event to the anchor tags only.

Comment: @tlm Can you tell me why it works on the page where the element is placed and the javascript file console.log told me other values?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your code is trying to do above but in the for loop, when you call console.log(this.className) outside of the event handler, `this.className` will be undefined because there is not context for `this` outside of your event handler, i.e. there is not className because `this` is no longer your button element once you're outside of your event handler.  Second, I don't see where you're using the user_admin function.  And, are you sure that you're loading your js files prior to the DOM being populated with the HTML elements.

Comment: @tlm For better understanding see my the updated post (Update 3)

Comment: @sokolata okay, but where you are attaching your event handler?  Does that happen somewhere in core.js?

Comment: @tlm you mean the click event handler? This is attached in index.php because there are also attached the buttons.